# ImportError: cannot import name 'factor' from 'plotnine'

Tags: python, import, plotnine

I try to use the factor option in plotnine.

My code is:

from plotnine import ggplot, aes, geom_bar, factor

I get this error.

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
> last) Cell In[1], line 1
> ----> 1 from plotnine import ggplot, aes, geom_bar, factor
> 3 # Sample data
> 4 data = {
> 5     'Category': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
> 6     'Value': [10, 15, 5, 20]
> 7 }
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'factor' from 'plotnine'
> (C:\Users...\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\ora\lib\site-packages\plotnine_*init*_.py)

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

I tried to import factor from plotnine. The same problem occurs when I try to import reorder

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that there's no module or function named `factor` directly within the `plotnine` library, which is why you're getting an `ImportError`.

In `plotnine`, you don't need to import `factor` or `reorder` directly like you would in R's `ggplot2`. Instead, you'd use pandas functions or other Python methods to handle factors and ordering.

If you want to create a factor-like variable or reorder categories in Python with pandas, here's how you might do it:

Convert a column to a categorical type.

```
import pandas as pd
data['Category'] = pd.Categorical(data['Category'])
```

Change the order of the categories.

```
data['Category'] = pd.Categorical(data['Category'], categories=['B', 'A', 'C', 'D'], ordered=True)
```

Then :

```
import pandas as pd
from plotnine import ggplot, aes, geom_bar

# Sample data
data = {
    'Category': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'Value': [10, 15, 5, 20]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Category'] = pd.Categorical(df['Category'], categories=['B', 'A', 'C', 'D'], ordered=True)

# Plotting
plot = (
    ggplot(df, aes(x='Category', y='Value')) +
    geom_bar(stat='identity')
)
print(plot)
```

Answer (score 0):

In plotnine `factor` and `reorder` are internal functions that you can only use in `aes` string expressions. e.g.

```
aes(x="factor(column1)")
```